# MySQL, rows dissapearing

Tags: python, mysql, excel

I've run into an unusual problem that will likely highlight my unfamiliarity with MySQL. I have over 1000 excel files I need to upload to a MySQL server. I wrote a simple python program using mysql.connector and xlrd, (python 2.7 just for reference). The program essentially gathers the relevant data and then adds it using

```
"INSERT INTO realposts "
"(PostId, Subreddit, Title, Body, Username, NumberofComments, Upvotes, CreationTime, Link, Gilded, SFW)"
"VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
"ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE NumberofComments =  NumberofComments, Upvotes = Upvotes, Gilded = Gilded;"
```

So far, so good! I added about 400 excel files, no problems. Then I added another 400, so far so good. I got to the last 200 however, and when doing a quick analysis of the data, noticed that when I did

```
select subreddit, count(*) from realposts
group by subreddit;
```

that an entire category, with supposedly over 1000 entries, had just vanished.

Can someone point me at what might possibly have caused this, and how to address it? I'm extremely unfamiliar with MySQL, but searching shows that this shouldn't be happening. I'm not sure how to even begin debugging this.

EDIT: And somehow, after running it for the fourth time, the bug has disappeared. I'll leave this open, but I have no answer as to why.

Comment: If you're unfamiliar with MySQL, then if possible I'd recommend a switch to PostgreSQL...

Comment: What is the definition for the realposts table?  Specifically the primary key.

Comment: The primary key is PostId with a Datatype of varchar(6) and set to NN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this turned out to be an issue with displaying tables in mysql workbench, I had set the limit of rows to 1000, which is why it wasn't displaying some results, which I erroneously thought it had eaten.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

I did some research for you and one of these possibilities may have happened:

1)The data never got to the database in the first place. Something happened elsewhere so the data disappeared. Maybe intermittent network issues, overloaded server, application bug.

2)A database transaction was not committed, and got rolled back. Maybe a bug in your application code, maybe some invalid data screwed things up, maybe a concurrency exception occurred etc.

3)A bug in MySQL.

Comment: yep, saw this when I searched around for solutions to the problem. The same page said it shouldn't be #3. But I'm 100% sure I'm commiting the changes (in fact, I can see them!)

If it is an application bug, how do I go about tracking it down? Its a local server so its not a connectivity issue.